# grepl ifelse doesn't show the right value (R)

Tags: r, if-statement, text, grepl

I tried to create a column "gender" based on the name of people. I have multiple names, sometimes composed of two names (for instance William Alexander). Here is my code (an extract, i have much more than that names)

```
df$gender <- ifelse(grepl("LUIS|OSCAR|HELMUT|PABLO",df$names, ignore.case = T), "Man",
             ifelse(grepl("VIVIANA|DIANA|ADRIANA|ALBA",df$names, ignore.case = T), "Woman","NA"))
```

I though that the code was working perfectly well, but i denoted the following thanks to a group_by :

| Names | Gender |
| --- | --- |
| Luis | Man |
| Alba Tatiana | Man |

I don't understand why a woman name appears as a man name even if i specified that it should takes the value "Woman"

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue.  Are you sure that the column name is `'names'` instead of `Names`?.  I get `[1] "Man"   "Woman"` from your code I assumed column name as 'names'

Comment: I wrote "names" here for more confidentiality but on R the name of the column is rightly specified for both ifelse.

Comment: As I said, I get the `Man` and `Woman` from your example.  May be you could show the `dput` of the example

Comment: The dput(df) identifies ALBA as hombre. This is driving me crazy because it's the only name for which i have an error !

Comment: Probably you have some encoding issue.  Please check you locale settings

Comment: Okay i'll do that, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

As akrun already indicates `names` in code vs. `Names` in df is the problem:

```
df$gender <- ifelse(grepl("LUIS|OSCAR|HELMUT|PABLO",df$Names, ignore.case = T), "Man",
                    ifelse(grepl("VIVIANA|DIANA|ADRIANA|ALBA",df$Names, ignore.case = T), "Woman","NA"))
df
```

Output:

```
  Names        Gender gender
  <chr>        <chr>  <chr> 
1 Luis         Man    Man   
2 Alba Tatiana Man    Woman
```

Comment: Sorry it's my fault i wrote in lower case in the table, but i have upper case both in the code and in the dataset !